# Can someone please explain the meaning of the circled paragraph?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

[image: image from principles of quantum mechanics] why does the off diognal elements of the matrix mediate with the coupling differential equation?

Comment: Well, seems someone mixed up their plurals in that para...

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: ok...it was such a long text thats why i  was sorta lazy..

Answer (score 2):

The off-diagonal elements cause the second derivative of $x_1$ to depend on $x_2$ and *vice versa*. That’s what it means to have *coupled* differential equations.

If the off-diagonal elements are zero, then you have two *uncoupled* equations: one for $x_1$ and one for $x_2$.

Uncoupled equations are easier to solve because you can solve each one separately from the other.

Comment: thanks that helped..but solving without diagonlistion shouldnt be wrong,right?

Comment: If you can solve them *without* decoupling them by diagonalizing the matrix, it’s fine to do it that way. (However, if you are in school your teacher may want you to do it in a particular way.)